# Routing through Tails OS

Tags: anonymity, tor

Is it possible to route all my traffic of Kali Linux through a virtual machine or laptop that is using Tails OS in the same network?

This question is related to anonymity I guess someone can help me here?

Comment: Why do you want the traffic to go through a Tails VM, specifically?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible as Whonix already does this.

Whonix comes with two VM:

1. Server

   a) Which establish a Tor tunnel and route all traffic through it

   b) It has two NIC, one bridge or NAT; one internal with the client
2. Client

   a) All its traffic goes through the Server-Tor-Tunnel.

   b) Only has one NIC internal with the Server

You could use the Whonix server instance in front of your Kali VM or replicate the Whonix Server configuration on your Tail VM.